# Switching Default Interface to Route Traffic

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I want to switch primary network interface of my Ubuntu machine, I referenced this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setup-default-gateway-with-route-command/.

Here is my setting for experiments: I use a router to provide connection for both wlan0 and eth0, with different IP (192.168.1.115 and 192.168.1.130 respectively, gateway 192.168.1.1). Normally eth0 is the default one, so I do:

```
route delete gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
route add gw 192.168.1.1 wlan0
```

Interestingly, although 192.168.1.115 is now the dominant IP, but I see incoming traffic captured in eth0 with 192.168.1.115 as destination IP, and outbound packet in wlan0 as expected.

Why this is happening? And what is the correct way to do that interface switching?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Linux uses the "weak host" model on IPv4; that is, it answers ARP requests for any address assigned to the *system*, even if they came through a different interface.

So when the router broadcasts an ARP request for `.115`, your host receives it through both interfaces, sends answers via both, and the router receives the answer over Ethernet first.

There are two sysctl tunables to change this behavior:

- `net.ipv4.conf.*.arp_filter`

  Described in [Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt:1032](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt#n1032).

  > 1 - Allows you to have multiple network interfaces on the same
  >   subnet, and have the ARPs for each interface be answered
  >   based on whether or not the kernel would route a packet from
  >   the ARP'd IP out that interface (therefore you must use source
  >   based routing for this to work).
- `net.ipv4.conf.*.arp_ignore`

  Described in [Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt:1082](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt#n1082).

  > 1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
  >   configured on the incoming interface

For example, you could set the following in `sysctl.d`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
```

(Note that I'm not completely sure which setting is suitable in what situation.)

Comment: I used the two nrp_ignore one, they seem more suitable, but after I switched, my router often have trouble to send packet back to me. Requests are sent out normally on wlan0, but never coming back.